# Will I lose comments in Overleaf if I use git as well?

Tags: overleaf, git

I am collaborating in an Overleaf project where I use git to work locally while my colleagues work directly on the browser.

On top of editing, they also use Overleaf's comments (see [url](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Track_Changes_in_Overleaf#Resolve,_re-open_and_delete_comment_threads)) to talk to one another.

If I commit my local changes to Overleaf, do I risk accidentally deleting their comments? Is there some file where Overleaf keeps these comments used in the browser?

Comment: This does not seem to the related to TeX and friends. Perhaps a better question for Overleaf support.

Comment: I made the question here because I've found other questions regarding Overleaf and because it's a possibly recurrent question. But thanks for your comment, I'll check with their support.

Comment: Since it is about implementation details for OverLeaf hereis not the correct place to ask. It is true that Overleaf support scans the site

Comment: @ClaudenirFonseca I have the same question; if/when you have any updates on this, could you post an update/answer please?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou done.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Overleaf's Git feature for a while now and it seems like you risk losing comments created online. It seems that you can lose the comments if your update changes the commented lines.

Still, if you want to use Git only to update resources of your project like figures (I do this a lot), that is safe. Another option would be to convince your collaborators to use some LaTeX solution for commenting, like [`\usepackage{todonotes}`](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/619-tip-of-the-week-add-inline-or-margin-comments-to-your-pdf#:%7E:text=In%20LaTeX%2C%20you%20can%20use,can%20use%20the%20todonotes%20package.&text=Tags%3A,guides).

Comment: Thank you for updating! That's what I had suspected too, so it's good to confirm. Regarding `todonotes`, if I'm allowed a shameless plug, in case it may interest future visitors: I find that it usually doesn't work for me, as it requires _really_ generous margins, and journal article templates usually don't have that. So I use my hacky homemade alternative instead (see under dependencies/macros here: https://git.sr.ht/~tpapastylianou/a-tidy-latex-project-template )