# How does pulling from github effect overleaf comments (i.e., not inline (%) latex comments)

Tags: overleaf, comments

I am working on a project in overleaf where a collaborator has left some comments. I have simultaneously worked offline on the project and want to merge my changes into overleaf but I am worried that they will remove the comments. Does anyone know what happens?

Thanks

Comment: You could use Git for merging.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @dexteritas - I do intend to use git. I am worried that when I perform the merge, the comments in overleaf will be lost?

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem (overleaf comments and not just edits to the file), but I don't know the answer. I found a duplicate: [Will I lose comments in Overleaf if I use git as well?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595454/123129), but there are no answers. And some related information: [Saving comments and correction in a file overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580975/123129).

Comment: Hello there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. Our system tries to get this right, but it's tricky, so it can happen that the comments get misplaced or lost when you push from Git. If you rename or move a file with comments, your comments might be lost, and if you delete a chunk of text that has a comment associated with it, that comment may be lost or detached. If you are simply editing a file and do not delete the part with comments, they should be preserved. As a side not: I'm not sure how much is this on-topic here -- you can always reach us at https://www.overleaf.com/contact if needed.

Comment: Hi both thank you for your help - all makes sense :)